# How can I formulate an ldap query looking for the absence of an attribute

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I want to query my directory for all User objects that don't contain a value for a given attribute... I have kind of hacked it up looking for things without a specific value (the potential assigned values are small, so this mostly worked) - but I would really like to know if there is a way to actually query for the absence of an attribute... kind of analogous to a relational database null.

Here is the query I ended up using:

```
(&(objectClass=User)(!extensionAttribute1=A))
```

Any ideas how to write an LDAP query looking for objects where an attribute has not been defined? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 7):

We need a few more parens when doing this:

`(&(objectClass=User)(!(extensionAttribute1=*)))`

If you want to look for a particular attribute you need to remove some parens (removing the ! is not enough)

`(&(objectClass=User)(extensionAttribute1=*))`

Answer (score 2):

(&(objectClass=User)(!extensionAttribute1=*))